# Filtering exact match and concatenating in a new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have `df` as

```
acc_id  acc_status  username    TeamMemRole             email
A1      Inactive    A           Serv Primary            a@ab.com
A1      Inactive    B           Sales - Primary         b@ab.com
A1      Inactive    C           Ent Specialist          c@ab.com
A2      Inactive    D           Sales - Primary         d@ab.com
B1      Inactive    E           Tech Sales - Primary    e@ab.com
B1      Inactive    F           Ent Specialist          f@ab.com
B1      Inactive    G           Sales - Primary         g@ab.com
C1      Inactive    H           Sales - Primary         h@ab.com
C1      Inactive    I           Sales - Secondary       a@ab.com
C1      Inactive    J           Tech Sales - Primary    j@ab.com
```

I want all the the emails expect `Sales - Primary` for that particular `acc_id` to be concatenated and be in a separate column and the emails of only `Sales - Primary` in a separate column as below

```
acc_id  acc_status    username     TeamMemRole            email       To         CC
A1      Inactive      A            Serv Primary           a@ab.com    b@ab.com  a@ab.com,c@ab.com
A1      Inactive      B            Sales - Primary        b@ab.com      
A1      Inactive      C            Ent Specialist         c@ab.com      
A2      Inactive      D            Sales - Primary        d@ab.com    d@ab.com  
B1      Inactive      E            Tech Sales - Primary   e@ab.com    g@ab.com  e@ab.com,f@ab.com 
B1      Inactive      F            Ent Specialist         f@ab.com      
B1      Inactive      G            Sales - Primary        g@ab.com      
C1      Inactive      H            Sales - Primary        h@ab.com    h@ab.com  a@ab.com,j@ab.com
C1      Inactive      I            Sales - Secondary      a@ab.com      
C1      Inactive      J            Tech Sales - Primary   j@ab.com
```

I tried using

```
df[df['TeamMemRole'].str.contains('Sales - Primary')==False]
```

but this is removing `Tech Sales - Primary` as well.

Please help with any suggestions and approaches

Comment: There's `Sales Primary` in your data (without dash). Is it intentional?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, just fixed it, Its ```Sales - Primary``` everywhere

Comment: Would you mind giving a sample of your data?

Comment: The data is pretty similar to what I have put up.
1. The ```acc_id``` is unique
2. The ```Sales - Primary``` needs to be in a column for that particular column
3. Every other ```TeamMemRole``` needs to be concatenated and put in a separate column for the respective accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
# first row for each group
first_rows = ~df['acc_id'].duplicated()

# primary sale rows
prim_sale_rows = df['TeamMemRole'].eq('Sales - Primary')

# To column
prim_sales = df.loc[prim_sale_rows].groupby('acc_id')['email'].apply(', '.join)
df.loc[first_rows, 'To'] = df['acc_id'].map(prim_sales)

# CC column
CC_list = df.loc[~prim_sale_rows].groupby('acc_id')['email'].apply(', '.join)
df.loc[first_rows, 'CC'] = df['acc_id'].map(CC_list)
```

Output:

```
  acc_id acc_status username           TeamMemRole     email        To                  CC
0     A1   Inactive        A          Serv Primary  a@ab.com  b@ab.com  a@ab.com, c@ab.com
1     A1   Inactive        B       Sales - Primary  b@ab.com       NaN                 NaN
2     A1   Inactive        C        Ent Specialist  c@ab.com       NaN                 NaN
3     A2   Inactive        D       Sales - Primary  d@ab.com  d@ab.com                 NaN
4     B1   Inactive        E  Tech Sales - Primary  e@ab.com  g@ab.com  e@ab.com, f@ab.com
5     B1   Inactive        F        Ent Specialist  f@ab.com       NaN                 NaN
6     B1   Inactive        G       Sales - Primary  g@ab.com       NaN                 NaN
7     C1   Inactive        H       Sales - Primary  h@ab.com  h@ab.com  a@ab.com, j@ab.com
8     C1   Inactive        I     Sales - Secondary  a@ab.com       NaN                 NaN
9     C1   Inactive        J  Tech Sales - Primary  j@ab.com       NaN                 NaN
```

Comment: Thank a ton for the help. this works like a charm.  I was trying to understand the code

Comment: with ```first_rows```  and ```prim_sale_rows``` you are getting out the unique acc_id and only ```'Sales - Primary```